# How to Logout Account Only in One Device

Tags: support, feature-request, logout

I have a computer at home and I am logged in to stackoverflow using my facebook account. After using stackoverflow, I close my browser without signing out my account, making it automatically logged-in next time I opened the site.
I also use another computer (from internet cafe / school / work) and I logged in to stackoverflow with my facebook account. After using, I want to sign out in order to secure my account.
I noticed that when signing out, I saw the message that my account will be logged out in ALL devices. So, when I open stackoverflow in home PC, my account is not logged in.

Is there any way to sign-out account in only one device(the computer at internet cafe / school / work )?

Comment: Not at all. It would complicate the UI, and make things more error-prone. It's far more important that SE does not forget to log out of some device you forgot about having used, than only logging out of one device.

Comment: What if you log out of Facebook on the device that you want to log out of Stackoverflow from?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek why would that have any impact on an OpenID login? SO does not know if anybody is logged in to FB or not, they just authenticate the user once with their OpenID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear your cookies on that device.  If you remove the cookie from that device, rather than telling SE to treat that cookie as an invalid cookie, you'll still prevent automatic login from that machine.

SE does not provide a built in mechanism to invalidate one of the cookies without invalidating all of the others.

Comment: Another method to point out that basically does the same thing is if you're using Stack Overflow at a location temporarily, use private browsing.

Comment: Clearing cookies and history can make the browser forget what I'm doing.

Comment: @Mai Then don't clear the history if you don't want to clear the history; clear just the cookies instead, or if you *really* need to, just clear SE's cookie.